# Suggested edit approved with only two votes?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I was about to improve a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1547835) when I noticed it was already approved. When I checked, I saw it took only two "Approve" votes instead of three. A bug maybe?

I recently saw someone describing a similar problem here (couldn't find the link), and it was a problem with the facebook sub-site. This is apparently different.

Comment: Specifically, "The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification of their post."

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't notice that. Voting to close too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original poster approved the edit; if they approve the edit, then it automatically goes through.